# Sum Colum case () after pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot-table

Sorry if I don´t explain very well, and the title isn´t very clear.
I´m using SQL Server 2005.
I have a query with Pivot that is working fine, but know I must add a new query that get resuls from quarterly.

This is my query to get result from Month

```
    WITH PivotData AS
(
SELECT  idWatimetro, mes,ano, valor
FROM   E_Registros_Watimetros where ano = 2012
)
SELECT *
FROM PivotData 
PIVOT(SUM(valor) FOR idWatimetro IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5] AS P order by mes;
```

[image]

So, know only I want to get four registres

```
1 With Month 1+2+3
2 Wint Month 4+5+6
3 With Month 7+8+9
4 Wint Month 10+11+12
```

[image]

I have been trying with UNION ALL but don´t work as I expected, Any help will be gratefull, and sorry for my bad english and explanation.

This is my query without result

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    (
            SELECT  idWatimetro, ano,mes, valor
            FROM E_Registros_Watimetros   
            WHERE (ano = 2012 and mes = 1 ) or (ano = 2012 and mes = 2)or (ano = 2012 and mes = 3)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  idWatimetro, ano,mes, valor
            FROM E_Registros_Watimetros    
            WHERE (ano = 2012 and mes = 4 ) or (ano = 2012 and mes = 5)or (ano = 2012 and mes = 6)
        ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT(SUM(valor) FOR idWatimetro IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]))AS P
```

Thanks advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like.....

```
   ; WITH PivotData AS
(
SELECT  idWatimetro
      ,CASE WHEN mes IN (1,2,3)    THEN 1
            WHEN mes IN (4,5,6)    THEN 2
            WHEN mes IN (7,8,9)    THEN 3
            WHEN mes IN (10,11,12) THEN 4
       END AS mes
      ,ano
      ,valor
FROM   E_Registros_Watimetros where ano = 2012
)
SELECT *
FROM PivotData 
PIVOT(SUM(valor) 
      FOR Mes 
      IN ([1],[2],[3],[4]))p
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY` quarter no., i.e. `mes - (mes - 1) % 3`, on the result set of the `PIVOT`:

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
   SELECT  idWatimetro, mes,ano, valor
   FROM   E_Registros_Watimetros where ano = 2012
),
PivotResult AS 
(
   SELECT *
   FROM PivotData 
   PIVOT(SUM(valor) FOR idWatimetro IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) AS P 
),
SELECT CASE mes - (mes - 1) % 3 
         WHEN 1 THEN '1st' 
         WHEN 4 THEN '2nd' 
         WHEN 7 THEN '3rd' 
         ELSE '4th' 
       END AS quarter,
       2012 AS ano, sum([1]) AS [1], sum([2]) AS [2], 
       sum([3]) AS [3], sum([4]) AS [4], sum([5]) AS [5]
FROM PivotResult
GROUP BY mes - (mes - 1) % 3
```